# Working of Apache Solr

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, solr, search-engine

Can anyone explain me how does Apache Solr works. I know how to create Solr instances and how to deploy that to Jetty and Tomcat. But under the hood **How does Apache Solr works** as it is a search library. So if I am searching anything from the interface of Apache Solr

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/
```

so we get some result back. So what happens under the hood. How Solr searching works?
I hope questions is clear enough. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Start by reading the **Solr tutorial** - http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html

Comment: I have read that tutorial. But it doesn't explain what happens under the hood when you search anything on the interface of Apache Solr.

Comment: This is a very broad question.

Comment: What do you mean under the hood? Do you want to know what solr does? It is a web view on top of a Lucene ( http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html ) index. You **have** to be specific if you want to have an answer. Do you have a question? What do you want to know? Are you having trouble using solr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you want to checkout how Solr work which includes what all it do once you hit the search button
Than the best way to to start learning Lucene.Solr is a wrapper around Lucene with some added functionality to make its user interface more easy to work with.

You need to know various things

1. How Solr/Lucene index data
2. How it parse the data. there are lot of Data handler for this.
3. How it read the query entered by the user.

I suggest you to go through Lucene wiki page and its various documents
[Apache Lucene](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/FrontPage?action=show&redirect=FrontPageEN)

once you are familiar with that download the source code, peek inside it how they are doing the things.
else if you have specific question about specific functionality better ask that question